# React source code: ReactCurrentOwner

Tags: reactjs

In React's source code, in ReactCurrentOwner.js I find this:

```
var ReactCurrentOwner = {

  /**
   * @internal
   * @type {ReactComponent}
   */
  current: (null: null | ReactInstance | Fiber),

};
```

What is going on here? I don't know how to begin to understand the syntax of the value for current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that it's using [flowtype](https://flowtype.org/) to describe that current is [null](https://flowtype.org/docs/builtins.html#null-and-void)

Comment: From what I can tell, the code is saying that the value for _current_ should be of type _null_, _ReactInstance_, or _Fiber_. Is that right? I can't seem to find anything on use of the pipe character in Flow's documentation.

Comment: That's my take as well. The pipe character is a [union type](https://flowtype.org/docs/union-intersection-types.html). Also, the null in front is a [Typecast](https://flowtype.org/blog/2015/02/18/Typecasts.html) which is setting current to `null` while also specifying the types allowed for it.